# Comparing current terminfo database against a terminfo source file

Tags: ncurses, terminfo

How can we compare all available terminfo entries (full current compiled database) against a terminfo source file ?

The `infocmp` utility has the `-F` option but it needs two files to be compared, but there isn't an option to export all entries and generate a file of the full current database, it needs to be called to each entry and so export each one of the entries separately. If there was a way to export all entries at once, it would be done in two steps, calling infocmp twice (one to export all database, and another to compare the files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could compile the source into a new directory and use `infocmp -d` to compare each entries.

```
mkdir -p dir && cd dir
TERMINFO=$PWD tic -x /path/to/terminfo.src
for entry in */*; do
  infocmp -x -d -B "$PWD" "${entry#*/}" "${entry#*/}"
done
```

To print only the differences with the relevant context only, you could do:

```
mkdir -p dir && cd dir
TERMINFO=$PWD tic -x /path/to/terminfo.src
for entry in */*; do
  LC_ALL=C infocmp -x -d -B "$PWD" "${entry#*/}" "${entry#*/}" |
    awk '
      /^comparing/ {entry=$1" "$2; next}
      $1 == "comparing" {section=$0; next}
      entry {print entry; entry = 0}
      section {print section; section = 0}
      {print}'
done
```

Comment: `infocmp` doesn't return different _exit codes_ when it find or not differences. So we need to parse the output to automate the process of getting just the differences.

Comment: @Luciano, yes. See edit for a possible way to reduce the clutter for entries or sections that have not changed.

Answer (score 1):

I do it with this script (on Debian, for instance which presumes that `kbs` is **`^?`**), to test local builds of ncurses:

```
#!/bin/sh
# $Id: test-terminfo+,v 1.10 2012/04/21 15:52:17 tom Exp $
# vi:sw=4 ts=4
# Compile the given terminfo source-file(s) into a temporary directory, compare
# the compiled files against the system version.
if test $# = 0 ; then
        with-local-ncurses $0 terminfo terminfo.src
else
        OPTS=-x
        MY_NCURSES=/usr/local/ncurses
        MY_TERMINFO=$MY_NCURSES/share/terminfo
        PATH=$MY_NCURSES/bin:$PATH; export PATH
        unset TERMINFO_DIRS
        unset TERMINFO
        TMP=/tmp/term$$
        rm -rf $TMP
        trap "rm -rf $TMP" 0 1 2 3 15
        mkdir $TMP
        rm -f $TMP/terminfo.sed
        cat >$TMP/terminfo.sed <<EOF
s,/usr/share,$MY_NCURSES/share,g
/^xterm+kbs|fragment for backspace key, kbs=/s/kbs=^H,/kbs=^?,/
/^xterm+kbs|fragment for backspace key,\$/,/^#/{
        s/kbs=^H,/kbs=^?,/
}
EOF
        for name in $*
        do
                if test -f "$name" ; then
                        sed -f $TMP/terminfo.sed $name >$TMP/source
                        TERMINFO=$TMP tic -U $OPTS -R ALL $TMP/source
                fi
        done
        TERMINFO=$MY_TERMINFO
        for name in $TMP/?/*
        do
                base=`dirname $name`
                base=`basename $base`
                name=`basename $name`
                case $name in
                ??)     # ignore 2-char termcap names
                        ;;
                *)
                        if test -f "$TERMINFO/$base/$name" ; then
                                infocmp -U $OPTS -q -p -f -A $TERMINFO -B $TMP $name $name
                        else
                                echo missing "$name $base"
                        fi
                        ;;
                esac
        done
fi
```

The log tells why some of the fine details matter:

```
----------------------------                                                                                
revision 1.10                                                                                               
date: 2012/04/21 15:52:17;  author: tom;  state: Exp;  lines: +2 -3                                         
add -x                                                                                                      
----------------------------                                                                                
revision 1.9                                                                                                
date: 2012/04/14 21:50:23;  author: tom;  state: Exp;  lines: +7 -4                                         
tweak to handle output from terminfo-uses script                                                            
----------------------------                                                                                
revision 1.8                                                                                                
date: 2012/03/17 19:31:02;  author: tom;  state: Exp;  lines: +15 -4                                        
tweaks to make this compare more closely to what I've installed, by                                         
accounting for the pathnames used in cfg-local                                                              
----------------------------                                                                                
revision 1.7                                                                                                
date: 2011/08/10 08:49:23;  author: tom;  state: Exp;  lines: +2 -2                                         
make this work with Solaris                                                                                 
----------------------------                                                                                
revision 1.6                                                                                                
date: 2011/06/11 17:23:15;  author: tom;  state: Exp;  lines: +2 -2                                         
remove spurious "eval" when doing no-args                                                                   
----------------------------                                                                                
revision 1.5                                                                                                
date: 2004/07/05 14:06:46;  author: tom;  state: Exp;  lines: +15 -7                                        
use -U option to simplify comparing termcap                                                                 
ignore 2-char termcap names                                                                                 
----------------------------                                                                                
revision 1.4                                                                                                
date: 2004/01/31 17:42:01;  author: tom;  state: Exp;  lines: +2 -2                                         
ignore padding                                                                                              
----------------------------                                                                                
revision 1.3                                                                                                
date: 2003/05/31 21:00:37;  author: tom;  state: Exp;  lines: +9 -5                                         
use local-ncurses rather than installed version                                                             
----------------------------                                                                                
revision 1.2                                                                                                
date: 2002/06/22 22:31:53;  author: tom;  state: Exp;  lines: +1 -1                                         
add -p option                                                                                               
----------------------------                                                                                
revision 1.1                                                                                                
date: 2001/05/19 20:07:23;  author: tom;  state: Exp
```

I check for differences (other than *missing* entries) by looking for <kbd>*tab*</kbd> characters.

As for why it is named `test-terminfo`**+**, that is because the original script (written in 1998) compared only against the system terminfo (there weren't any packages to avoid contaminating...).

As usual, it helps to read the manual pages:

- [**`tic`** - the terminfo entry-description compiler](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tic.1m.html)
- [**`infocmp`** - compare or print out terminfo descriptions](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/infocmp.1m.html)

Comment: It seems the `ALL` in `-R ALL` is not documented. Does that imply that without it, only a subset is generated? I can see `-R` is also an option of `infocmp`. Is it not needed there as well?

Comment: What do you think of having `infocmp -d` reflect whether the two entries are the same or not in the exit status like for `diff`/`cmp`?

Comment: There's pros/cons: while it might seem a good idea, copying the cmp/diff exit status would make it return a different code for failure than it does now, and would cause any existing script that checks the status to fail.  That's because `EXIT_FAILURE` is (usually) defined to **1**.

Comment: With `-R`, the `ALL` value happens to work: only the documented values do a subset; anything else is the full set.  Another to-do item :-)

Comment: Looking at the code, it also looks like `-I`, `-C`, `-r` cancel the effect of `-R` which may be worth  documenting (`-C -r` seems to also be different from `-r -C`)